# how can I plot a column of circles with diameter proportional to the values of a list? in R

Tags: r, plot, geometry

I have a list of groups, each one with certain values associated.

```
states<-c("a1","a2","a3","a4","a5","a6","a7","a8","a9","a10","a11","a12")
values<-c(6.285846,7.494191,8.787820,5.019964,8.496752,7.038441,6.189049,5.083978,5.889171,5.666400,7.460571,6.803635)
```

Now I would like to plot the names of my groups, next to a circle with diameter proportional to the value associated to the group, in two columns preferably, one for the names, and the other for the circles.

is there a way to do so easily in R?

thank you very much in advance.

Tina.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A very basic implementation using `cex` and base graphics:

```
plot(rep(0, 12), 1:12, cex=values/2)
text(rep(-.5,12), 1:12, states)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want a little more control of the size of the circles then look at the `symbols` function.